# Prove that $-(a-b)=b-a$ and $(a-b)(c-d)=(ac+bd)-(ad+bc)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Prove that

1. $-(a-b)=b-a$
2. $(a-b)(c-d)=(ac+bd)-(ad+bc)$

for any $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

**Solution of 1.**

First, I will show that the additive inverse of the additive inverse of some element $a$ is the element $a$ itself, i.e. $-(-a)=a$. It's obvious, since
$-(-a)=-(-a)+0=-(-a)+(-a+a)=(-(-a)+(-a))+a=a$.

Another useful fact is that $-1 a = -a$, since
$-1 a+1 a=a(1-1)=0$.

Now we can easily show 1.

$b-a=-(-b)-a=-1(a-b)=-(a-b)$.

**Solution of 2.**

$(a-b)(c-d)=a(c-d)+(-b)(c-d)=ac+a(-d)+(-b)c+(-b)(-d)=ac-ad-bc+bd=(ac+bd)-(ad+bc)$

I used  $(-1)(-1)=1$ and previous facts.

Comment: What's your definition of $a-b$?

Comment: @Wojowu AfaIk, this is always defined as $a + (-b)$.

Comment: $a+(-b)$ ($a$ $+$ additive inverse of $b$)

Comment: @StefanPerko We can also define it as "the unique $x$ such that $a=x+b$. Of course these are equivalent, but I wanted to know which one OP uses.

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, I see. Nevermind then.

Comment: No problems here, not the neatest manner but it's more than enough :)